# Hypoventilation training

Tags: muscle

Hypoventilation training is used by many  top tier world athletes to perform better in their sports and require less training overall.
Basically exhaling and then holding your breath as you perform physical activities.
Then there's also the idea of blood flow restriction, which makes achieving hypertrophy easier by decreasing oxygen.

But does Hypoventilation training work with hypertrophy training too? Or as it been tested only for Olympic events?